# Javascript replace values in a string

Tags: javascript

I am framing a Javascript string as follows as per my requirement:

```
var empDetails= "ID=" + id + ";" + "Name=XYZ" + ";" + "Address=ABC";
// id is autoincremented like 1,2,3 and so on.

if (sessionStorage.getItem('empDet') === null) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('empDet', empDetails);
} else {
    var empDets= sessionStorage.getItem('empDet');
    var pResult = empDets;
    if (pResult.length > 0) {
        var ptotalEmp= empDets.toString().concat(';' + empDetails.toString());
        sessionStorage.setItem('empDet', ptotalEmp);
    }
}
```

Now what I need to I will provide some option to edit the following details if user selected some id and if he change some thing related to `Name and Address` I need to update that and store. Can some one help me?

Comment: Did you tried something?

Answer (score 3):

You can store an object which I think is better than dealing with strings. If you have an object like:

```
var user = { id: 1, name: "ABC", address: "DEF" };
```

You can *stringify* it with `JSON.stringify` to store on local storage. Then retrieve it using *JSON.parse*:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
var u = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('user'));
```

Now use it as an object:

```
u.name = "Foo";
u.address = "Bar";
```

See it on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uAEtS/).

By the way, you can easily use a function for that.

Answer (score 2):

for this better way is that you can use some other character in the place where you concat your new empDetails with the existing ones..

Eg. you can change it like  `var ptotalEmp= empDets.toString().concat('|' + empDetails.toString());` in the below code..

```
if (sessionStorage.getItem('empDet') === null) {
                sessionStorage.setItem('empDet', empDetails);
            }
            else {
                var empDets= sessionStorage.getItem('empDet');
                var pResult = empDets;
                if (pResult.length > 0) {
                    var ptotalEmp= empDets.toString().concat('|' + empDetails.toString());
                    sessionStorage.setItem('empDet', ptotalEmp);
                }
            }
```

so that now you can spit each emp details with `'|'` symbol and then get the details, update it and store it.

Answer (score 0):

How about :

```
var empDetails= "ID=" + id + ";" + "Name=XYZ" + ";" + "Address=ABC";
function updateDetails(str,name,addr) {
    var reg = /ID=(\d+);Name=(.*?);Address=(.*?)$/;
    var fin = reg.exec(d);
    return "ID="+fin[1]+";"+"Name="+(name?name:fin[2])+";"+"Address="+(addr?addr:fin[3])+";";
}
updateDetails(empDetails,"replacement");
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, done it! I created 3 functions for you to set, get and clear that particular sessionstorage item.

**Here is the code:**

```
function setValue(){
    var id = document.getElementById("id"),
        name = document.getElementById("name"),
        address = document.getElementById("address"),
        item = "ID=" + id.value + ";NAME=" + name.value + ";ADDRESS=" + address.value;

    if(sessionStorage.getItem('empDet')){
        var existing = getValue().split("||"),
            repaced = false;

        for(var i = 0; i<existing.length; i++){
            if(existing[i].split(";")[0].split("=")[1] == id.value){
                existing[i] = item;
                repaced = true;
            }
        }

        item = repaced ? existing  : existing + "||" + item;
    }
    sessionStorage.setItem('empDet', item);    
    id.value = name.value = address.value = "";
}

function getValue(cry){
    var existing = sessionStorage.getItem('empDet');
    if(cry){
        alert(existing);
    }
    return existing;
}

function clearValue(){
    sessionStorage.removeItem('empDet');
}
```

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/hu2V3/1/

You can customize it according to your own need.

**=================== EDIT ===================**

Got a suggestion in a comment that playing with JSON object is better than playing with String, which is really helpful. So, updated the code a bit and now it's JSON based.

```
function setValue(){
    var id = document.getElementById("id"),
        name = document.getElementById("name"),
        address = document.getElementById("address"),
        item = {
            ID : id.value,
            NAME : name.value,
            ADDRESS : address.value
        },
        allTogether = [],
        repaced = false;

    if(sessionStorage.getItem('empDet')){
        allTogether = JSON.parse(getValue());

        for(var i = 0; i < allTogether.length; i++){
            if(allTogether[i].ID == id.value){
                allTogether[i] = item;
                repaced = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if(!repaced){
        allTogether.push(item);
    }

    sessionStorage.setItem('empDet', JSON.stringify(allTogether));    
    id.value = name.value = address.value = "";
}
```

updated Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/hu2V3/2/